# Как получить все объекты в скрипте

Tags: javascript, объекты, класс

Есть класс в JS, у которого несколько экземпляров. Можно ли как-то получить все созданные в скрипте объекты?

Comment: Если переменные видны как `window['Variable Name']`, то можно пройтись по всему что есть в `window` и с помощью [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) проверять. Ну или можно при создании каждого объекта записывать его куда-то

Comment: переменные не видны через window['Var'].

Comment: Тогда записывайте их куда-то при создании